# Text-to-Speech working but not as intended on swift iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, text-to-speech

I have a button that triggers a text-to-speech function.
When I run it, it works as intended when I press the button :)
I can even run it a few times on that screen and it works consistently, almost.
What I have found is that if I press the button more than 4 times on the one screen, it doesn't work anymore.

What I have also found that if I go back to the previous screen, click a new phrase and go into my text-tospeech screen it doesn't play it at all.

Here is the code that invokes the text-to-speech:

```
@IBAction func TextToSpeech(sender: UIButton) {

    myUtterance = AVSpeechUtterance(string: TranslationLanguage.text)
    myUtterance.voice = AVSpeechSynthesisVoice(language: "el-GR")
    myUtterance.rate = 0.2
    synth.speakUtterance(myUtterance)
    synth.pauseSpeakingAtBoundary(.Word)  
}
```